# 404 error when debugging an Aviarc application

Tags: aviarc

I open the Aviarc debugger and select my application from the list. I set a breakpoint in a workflow and then I Run to Next Screen, Workflow, Breakpoint.

I get a 404 error. My application works fine on it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application is only accessible from workflow urls. The root url is not operational hence the 404.

Instead of selecting my application from the list of apps I had to put the full url in the 'Url to debug' field on the initial debugger screen. Problem solved.